# grep exact process name in bash script with variable argument

Tags: bash, grep, process, arguments

I'm writing a bash script where I want to grep the name of a process. This name is the argument when the script is executed.

Normally I can do this `ps -ef | grep [w]ord` to get the correct processes.
How can I have the same effect when the argument to grep (here `[w]ord`) is something like `$1`

example:

`ps -ef | grep [f]fmpeg`

will show lines like this and nothing else

`jan       117977  117966  0 20:07 pts/0    00:00:01 ffmpeg ..`

when I want the same behavior within a script and make the argument to grep the argument from the script:

`ps -ef | grep "$1"`

and call it with `./script.sh ffmpeg` it will show me the ffmpeg processes (correct) but also the `grep` and `bash` process:

```
jan       117977  117966  0 20:07 pts/0    00:00:01 ffmpeg ..
jan       118566  117021  0 20:14 pts/4    00:00:00 bash ./script.sh ffmpeg
jan       118568  118566  0 20:14 pts/4    00:00:00 grep ffmpeg
```

I'm not interested in the last two lines of the output

Comment: Thanks to show us sample input and expected output

Comment: `ps` with `-f` displays the arg lists of the processes (same as `ps -o args`), not the process name (`ps -o comm`). To select processes by name (or arg list), use `pgrep` (or `pgrep -f`).

Comment: It's fine if it shows the arguments

Comment: `ps -ef | grep [w]ord` is wrong. `[w]ord` is *also* a glob to the shell, so is expanded to matching files first. Had you used a saner shell like `zsh`, you'd have seen a `no match` error (assuming there's no file called `word` in the current working directory). `ps -Af | grep '[w]ord'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply run:

```
pgrep -fl script.sh
```

From `man pgrep`:

> pgrep,  pkill,  pidwait  -  look  up, signal, or wait for processes based on name and other attributes
> `-f`, `--full`
> The  pattern  is  normally  only matched against the process name. When -f is set, the full command line is used.
> `-l`, `--list-name`
> List the process name as well as the process ID.  (pgrep only.)

Answer (score 1):

In shells that support it, you could use the substring expansion to put the brackets in the right places:

```
name=ffmpeg
ps -ef | grep "[${name:0:1}]${name:1}"
```

would run `grep "[f]fmpeg"` on the right hand side of the pipeline.

<sub>(That should be relatively safe with most special characters, since they're usually not special within brackets, but don't expect you'd have anything but letters there.)</sub>

Though `pgrep` is better in that it knows to ignore itself automatically. It just doesn't print everything `ps` does, but something like this might help with that:

```
name=ffmpeg
ps -f -p $(pgrep "$name" |tr '\n' ',')
```

Answer (score 0):

Would inverted-match with grep work?

```
grep -v 'grep\|script'
```

This will not match grep or script.